# Calling an VB.Net Shared method frpm .NET Core project throwing Runtime exceptions- When calling a method in vb.net dll

Tags: vb.net, .net-core

Calling an VB.Net Shared method of  .NET Core project throwing Runtime exceptions- When calling a method in vb.net dll

Throwing Runtime exception like below

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

When calling a mesage queue service which intern calling the another vb.net shared method.
 Seems there is some issue while calling a shared method of vb.net from .Net core 2.0 app

Comment: Do you have a sample project that reproduces this error in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This got fixed [just recently](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/28531).  "Surface issues" actually means that Interaction's accessibility had to be changed from Friend to Public.   You'd need the 2.1 preview to get the fix, presumably you did before to get this code to compile in the first place.  Be sure to run with it as well.  Or just copy/paste the function from source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualBasic/src/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Interaction.vb

Comment: Few methods were not migrated in older versions . So we face this issue. We wnt with the .net framework at that time